# How to prevent MongoDB from creating multiple records due to async

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, mongodb-query

My app is becoming a bit of a nightmare and this is a non-standard MongoDB problem I've not been able to find elsewhere.

My server flow is like this:

1. A user uploads a list of objects containing `{names, emails and company domains}` to my server
2. My server turns all of these into `Person` objects.
3. Once the `Person` has been saved, I search MongoDB to see whether a record for the person's `Domain` exists.
4. If it exists, I add the `Person`'s Mongo `_id` to a list of users from that `Domain`.
5. If it doesn't exist, I create a new `Domain` document and save it.

This works in theory, BUT, due to Async, sometimes I'm sending thousands of `Person` objects to the Domain saver function at once. Which means (at least, what I think is happening):

- Mongo searchers for "domain 1", sees there is no document so creates one, then saves one.
- While this is still happening,Mongo searches for "Domain 1" from a separate user. No document has been saved yet so it finds none and makes a new one.
- Now I have two documents with the same Domain identifier.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
Domain.findOne({
  domain: domn
}, function(err, rec) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Domain finding error: " + err)
    bigCount.doneDoms++;
    checkCount()
  } else if (rec){
    var tempObj = {}
        tempObj['$addToSet'] = { users: id }
        tempObj['$addToSet'].emails = user.email;

    if (userDoms.indexOf(rec._id) === -1) {
      userDoms.push(rec._id)
    }

    Domain.update({domain: domn}, tempObj, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Old rec save Error: " + err)
        bigCount.doneDoms++;
        checkCount();
      }else{
         // Saved Document
      }
    });

  } else { 
    var newDom = new Domain();
    newDom.domain = user.domain;
    newDom.company = user.company;
    newDom.users = [];
    newDom.users.push(id);
    newDom.emails = [];
    newDom.emails.push(user.email);

    newDom.save(function(err, record) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Dom save error: " + err)
      } else {
        // Saved Document
      }
    });

  }
})
```

Perhaps a stripped-down version of the question is, how do I handle somethign like this:

```
var arr = [{dom: 'dom1.com', user: 'James'}, {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "Phil"}, {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "Jess"} ...x1000... {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "Chris"];

for(var i - 0; i< arr.length; i++){
  var dom = arr[i]; var user = arr[i].user;
  Domain.findOne({domain: dom}, function(err, rec){
    if(rec){
      // Update old rec
      if(rec.users.indexOf(user) === -1){
         rec.users.push(user);
      }
      rec.save();
    ]else{

     // Make a new rec
     var rec = New Domain();
     rec.users = [user]
     rec.save();
    }
  })
}
```

Due to speed/Async, a lot of records are going to be created here, when really I only one want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally go on the approach that you are going about things the wrong way around, as well as that you could use some flow control in here.

Regardless of the "list" source, the general flow that should be happening is:

- Instantiate object for the user ( you get an `_id` in return after all )
- Look for the domain data if it exists, and if not then create it while adding the user at the same time. ( very possible )
- Finally add the matched domain to the user and save them

This all follows a pattern easily achieved with [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) along with the "upsert" option, which will create a new document if not found, and at any rate return the resulting document, either found or created.

So with some [node async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library helpers, here it is:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  domain: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Domain' }
});

var domainSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema),
    Domain = mongoose.model('Domain',domainSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/domains');

var arr = [
  {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "James"},
  {dom: 'dom2.com', user: "Phil"},
  {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "Jess"},
  {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "Chris"},
  {dom: 'dom3.com', user: "Jesse"}
];

async.series(
  [
    // Clean removal of data for demo
    function(callback) {
      async.each([User,Domain],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },

    // The actual insertion process
    function(callback) {
      async.eachLimit(arr,10,function(item,callback) {
        var user = new User({ name: item.user });

        // user already has the _id

        Domain.findOneAndUpdate(
          { "name": item.dom },
          { "$push": { "users": user._id } },
          { "new": true, "upsert": true },
          function(err,domain) {
            if (err) callback(err);
            user.domain = domain._id;   // always returns something

            // now save the user
            user.save(callback);
          }
        );

      },callback);
    },

    // List back populated as the proof
    function(callback) {
      User.find({}).populate('domain').exec(function(err,users) {
        if (err) callback(err);

        //console.log(users);
        //callback();

        var options = {
          path: 'domain.users',
          model: 'User'
        };

        User.populate(users,options,function(err,results) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          console.log( JSON.stringify( results, undefined, 2 ) );
          callback();
        });
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

And that will produce output like:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c2",
    "domain": {
      "_id": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
      "name": "dom1.com",
      "__v": 0,
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c2",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "James",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c4",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "Jess",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c5",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "Chris",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "James",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c3",
    "domain": {
      "_id": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff6",
      "name": "dom2.com",
      "__v": 0,
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c3",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff6",
          "name": "Phil",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "Phil",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c4",
    "domain": {
      "_id": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
      "name": "dom1.com",
      "__v": 0,
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c2",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "James",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c4",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "Jess",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c5",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "Chris",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "Jess",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c5",
    "domain": {
      "_id": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
      "name": "dom1.com",
      "__v": 0,
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c2",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "James",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c4",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "Jess",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c5",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff5",
          "name": "Chris",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "Chris",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c6",
    "domain": {
      "_id": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff7",
      "name": "dom3.com",
      "__v": 0,
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "55e6aa0e85e8b9102179f5c6",
          "domain": "55e6aa0ecb536c5a93574ff7",
          "name": "Jesse",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "Jesse",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

So all domains either got created or were re-used when then existed, and we added the user to the list in there at the same time using [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) since we already had the `_id` for the user once the instance was created.

With the domain document returned, being either new or something found, you simply set the domain on the user and save it.

The [`async.eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) is also a "special" variant that "limits" the number of concurrent processes to run under the loop. This is wise practice in real world scenarios, since you don't want to have every update happening at the same time.

Also, regardless of the process, the "Domain" cannot possibly get created more than once. The atomic operations of MongoDB will prevent this, and you only get an existing return or the new document depending on what was there at the time of the request.

As you can see in the output, everything can populate nicely so the "User" and "Domain" details are visible at all levels.

Moral of the story is *"Don't tie yourself in knots persisting one thing and altering again and again and again"*. Just do it once and be done with it. It's certainly faster.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. Although, I must say I *thought* I was following the principles that you're describing. I've created a gist of my code here: https://gist.github.com/jascination/327a9b11c213bb53b79e

This is based on the `async` suggestion below, but regardless Async is still creating multiple objects that contain the same data (except some just have one email in "emails", while others have all appropriate emails)

Comment: @Jascination If you follow what is being done in this answer then you will have no such problems. As said, using `.findOneAndUpate()` with "uspert" in the same pattern cannot possibly result in duplicate entries. This is a core design principle that it is not possible under this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

[§addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) together with [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) does exactly what you're looking for:

```
var items = [
    {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "Johnny"}, 
    {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "Doggie"}, 
    {dom: 'dom1.com', user: "Lisa"},
    {dom: 'dom2.com', user: "Mark"}, 
    {dom: 'dom3.com', user: "Denny"}
];

async.each(items, function(item, callback){
        Domain.findOneAndUpdate(
            {domain: item.dom}, 
            {$addToSet: {users: item.user}},
            { "new": true, "upsert": true }, 
            callback
        );
    }, 
    function (err){
        // done / handle errors
    }
);
```

Output:

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectID("55e6c9bf63006d730254ea8b"),
    "domain": "dom1.com",
    "users": [
        "Johnny",
        "Doggie",
        "Lisa"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectID("55e6c9bf63006d730254ea8c"),
    "domain": "dom2.com",
    "users": [
        "Mark"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectID("55e6c9bf63006d730254ea8d"),
    "domain": "dom3.com",
    "users": [
        "Denny"
    ]
}]
```

Comment: I've tried this, but for some bizarre reason I'm still getting the same results (that is, multiple records from the same domain).

Comment: Please check the edited answer, i think it fits exactly your problem